# symfony2 - output pdf page

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to create an action which will return a pdf (HTML to PDF).

I have a button in my twig file which calls in AJAX a routing pattern which will call the next controller action:

```
public function pageToPDFAction(){
    $html = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com");      
    $headers = array(
        'Content-type' => 'application/pdf'
    );
    $response = new Response($html,200,$headers);
    return $response;
}
```

The output I'm getting is in fact the google.com website, but what I want to get is the browser opening a pdf file like it happens when you click on a pdf file.

How can I achieve that? what am I missing?

Comment: You want a PDF of the contents of Google's web site?

Comment: @aserwin, googles website is an example, I need to output certain page of my website to a pdf when the user clicks on a certain button requesting it as pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [KnpSnappyBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle). It creates either pdf or image files from your html documents using the webkit engine. You can see example code in the `README` file.

Comment: I've tried implementing wkpdftohtml but I don't have write permissions to directories so I rather use something that doesn't ask me to create a file on the server, is there such thing?

Comment: Have you tried KnpSnappyBundle ? I don´t think it needs to write anything to disc, apart from /app/cache

Comment: I've tried KnpSnappyBundle but it requires to install many font libraries onto the linux machine which runs the server. I need something simple and straight forward.

Comment: I've tried installing this bundle on symfony2 but it didn't work. Is there a clear tutorial on how to install ? I guess that there are fonts that need to be installed , am I right?

Answer (score -2):

I have used psliwa's **[PHPPdf](https://github.com/psliwa/PHPPdf)** successfully in few projects and was very, very pleased with how it worked. Do check it out...

Comment: the documentation says: "Assumption of this library is not HTML -> PDF / JPEG / PNG, but XML -> PDF / JPEG / PNG transformation."

Comment: psliwa project is no longer supported

Comment: That's too bad. However,  before downvoting, please take into the consideration the date the answer was provided - almost 5 years ago.